# How to rename meta data entries in Quarto Book

Tags: quarto

I am using Quarto Book for writing an online Book for my students on scientific writing skills (see [www.politik-wissenschaft.at](https://www.politik-wissenschaft.at/)).

I want to add the bibliographic entry of this book at the start site (index.qmd / index.html). I used the abstract option for doing that. This works fine, but the title of this meta data entry is now called "Zusammenfassung" (i.e., abstract).

Is there a way to change this title to "How to cite", for example?

Furthermore, after updating Quarto CLI to 1.2.313 this information ("Zusammenfassung") is not only printed on the index.html file, but on the head of all other sites as well. How can I switched that off, so that these meta data information is only shown at the start site (i.e., index.html).

Comment: Concerning your second question, it should have been fixed in the last release. See [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/2282).

Comment: This bug seems to be back with the current version 1.2.313

Comment: Problem solved, see [https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/2282#discussioncomment-3585950](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/2282#discussioncomment-3585950)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the meta data using  [`template-partials`](https://quarto.org/docs/journals/templates.html#template-partials). Add the following to your `_quarto.yml` file:

```
template-partials:
  - title-block.html
```

And create the **title-block.html** file (see [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/src/resources/formats/html/pandoc/title-block.html) the original file) and change the *abstract-title* to your liking:

```
<header id="title-block-header">
<h1 class="title">$title$</h1>
$if(subtitle)$
<p class="subtitle">$subtitle$</p>

$endif$
$for(author)$
<p class="author">$author$</p>
$endfor$

$if(date)$
<p class="date">$date$</p>
$endif$
$if(abstract)$
<div class="abstract">
<div class="abstract-title">How to Cite </div>
$abstract$
</div>
$endif$
</header>
```

Different Option:

add a css file and change the text via css (usually not recommended):

**styles.css**

```
div.abstract-title {
  visibility: hidden;
}

div.abstract-title:before {
  content: "How to cite";
  visibility: visible;
}
```

[image]

Comment: that works fine, thank you. although the ORCID button is missing. However, this title-block.html is still showing up on all sites, and not only on the index.html site.

Comment: I made a different suggestion.

Comment: adding a custom.css works fine, thank you!